Flutter 3.22.3 Web Project not loading
I have a flutter project that runs in Android and iOS but when I try to run it on Web it not loads I just see the splash screen, I have a warning and an error in console.

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Camino App">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="cxapp">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

  <title>Camino</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <script>
    var dartPdfJsVersion = "3.2.146";
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer=""></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="splash/style.css">
  <!-- <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"> -->
  <script src="splash/splash.js"></script>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>

<body>  <picture id="splash">
      <source srcset="splash/img/light-1x.png 1x, splash/img/light-2x.png 2x, splash/img/light-3x.png 3x, splash/img/light-4x.png 4x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
      <source srcset="splash/img/dark-1x.png 1x, splash/img/dark-2x.png 2x, splash/img/dark-3x.png 3x, splash/img/dark-4x.png 4x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
      <img class="center" aria-hidden="true" src="splash/img/light-1x.png" alt="">
  </picture>      
  
  <script>
    self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = "ba100e01-7f3f-461b-9951-54c68b9d3eab";
  </script>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // ADD THIS LINE
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');

        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;

        //  ...
      });
    }
  </script>


</body></html>


In console I have this messages.
Rejecting promise with error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nativeCommunication')

---------

Uncaught (in promise) null

I have tried to update de index.html to a newer version but still dont work I spect to run the app in web with out problems.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

you should change index.html after flutter v3.22.
according to this ,the simplest way is :
First, remove the /web directory.
Then, from your project directory, run the following:
flutter create . --platforms=web 


I have tried that but still not working.
